# How to fetch a data from all tables from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have 3 columns in different tables in database. Tables names and numbers can be anything so I am not able to write query to fetch data from these three columns.

The query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name 
FROM (table names) 
WHERE email="someting@someting.com"
```

Please help me with this.

Thanks,

Edward

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Are you trying to get the union of all this tables ? thenyou should look at union keyword

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232626/posgresql-how-to-union-3-tables-sorted-by-date

Comment: If you don't know the tables names then it's going to be hard to do. In that case you'll have to lookup the table name in the system views, hope they are the ones you want, then build a query with them... Good luck or get someone to give you the correct tables names.

Comment: Select name from sys.tables   this query will fetch all the table name form the database but I don't know how to use this in my sql query ?

Answer (score 2):

You can build your SQL statement dynamically. Something akin to:

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(4000)

SET @SQL = 'SELECT first_name, last_name FROM .... etc'

EXEC (@SQL)

So assuming the table names you want to use are passed in as parameters or otherwise looked up from somewhere, you can include them in the query you build up in the @SQL variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, FromWhichTable 
FROM
(
   SELECT first_name, last_name, email, FromWhichTable = 1 FROM table_name1 
   UNION ALL
   SELECT first_name, last_name, email, 2                  FROM table_name2
   UNION ALL
   SELECT first_name, last_name, email, 3                  FROM table_name3 
) t
WHERE email="someting@someting.com"
```