# How can I speed up this feed-building process, which integrates multiple model types?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feed

I have a feed that is displayed to the user, which includes 4 different model types.

It simulates grouping the entries by day, by inserting a day object into the feed.

The feed is sorted chronologically and paginated.

This is how I currently build the feed.

```
def get_feed initial_feed_position=0, number_of_entries_to_get=30
  # display is called on each model to get them all into a standard format
  feed = (first_models + second_models + third_models + forth_models).map { |feed_entry| feed_entry.display }
  feed += day_entries_for_feed(feed)
  end_feed_position = initial_feed_position + number_of_entries_to_get
  (feed.sort_by { |feed_entry| -feed_entry[:comparison_time].to_i })[initial_feed_position...end_feed_position]
end

def day_entries_for_feed feed
  # iterate over a set of dates that contain feed entries
  feed.map{ |feed_entry| feed_entry[:date] }.uniq.map do |day|
    # building the day object in the standard feed entry format. fields that are not relevant to this question have been left out.
    {
      type: 'day',
      comparison_time: (day + 24.hours - 1.second).time # to ensure that the day appears above it's corresponding entries in the feed, the comparison time is set to 1 second before the day ends
    }
  end
end
```

Over time, the number of objects in the system has built up, and now the feed takes a long time to build using this method. Is there a better way to do it?

I'm using Rails 3.2.13, Ruby 1.9.3 & PostgreSQL 9.1.9.

Comment: `comparison_time: (day + 24.hours - 1.second).time` can be replaced with `comparison_time: day.end_of_day`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're getting all the entries in the database a lot of models are loaded into memory, to solve this problem you would have to look in to UNION (which is a pain to maintain and you will have to have literal SQL in your codebase). A good example of it is here: [PosgreSQL: How to union 3 tables sorted by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232626/posgresql-how-to-union-3-tables-sorted-by-date)

Another option would be to derive a base class and do the querying on this. Which would result in something like this:

```
                              +-------------+
                              |  BASE FEED  |
                              |             |
                              +------^------+
                                     |
        +-------------------+--------+---------+----------------+
        |                   |                  |                |
  +-----+-------+    +------+------+   +-------+-----+   +------+-----+
  |  MODEL ONE  |    |  MODEL TWO  |   | MODEL THREE |   | MODEL FOUR |
  |             |    |             |   |             |   |            |
  +-------------+    +-------------+   +-------------+   +------------+
```

Once you have your models set up like this it's a simple matter of querying this base table. Which could look something like this:

```
def get_feed(initial_feed_position = 0, number_of_entries_to_get = 30)
  feeds = BaseFeed.
    limit(number_of_entries_to_get).
    offset(initial_feed_position).
    order("DATE(date_field) DESC")
end
```

The above example is not the exact solution but if you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to get as a result set I can adjust it but it's more about the approach to take.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The feed elements are sorted on a Time field, but it is not the same Time field for each model. Some use model.created_at, others use model.sent_at. In the current system, I standardise the models by calling display on each of them, which converts them into a hash that has a key called comparison_time. Will your method work considering that?

Comment: You could do this by having a comparison time in the base feed table/class, you can then write this field before save on each of the derived classes. so f.e. ModelOne would have a before_save that would populate self.comparison_time with self.sent_at etc.

Answer (score 3):

Solution without changing the DB:

The reason your code is getting slower is that you query all the objects, and then taking 
only the top 30 (number_of_entries_to_get)

Because it's a feed, we can assume that most of the times, users will look at the first few pages.

Instead of taking all the first_models/second_models etc, you can take the newest end_feed_position straight from the db (order by date)

Something like:

```
models = FirstModel.order("date DESC").limit(end_feed_position)
models += SecondModel.order("created_at DESC").limit(end_feed_position)
```

So if, for example, you are on the page 2, and searching for a feed of 30:

You only query 240 objects from the db (first_models + second_models + third_models + forth_models) * 60 and it is places 30..60 in these 240 are the the 30..60 of all the objects (so it wont get slower as the db is growing)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added a comment to Novae's answer that also applies to this one.

Comment: This solution is working on different model fields, edited to make it clear.

Comment: I agree with the spirit of this solution; fundamentally, your problem is that you're not using your databases like real relational databases; you're just pulling out all of the data and manipulating it in memory.  You should be limiting your queries to return only the relevant data in the database(s).